# How can I count ocurrences of a line in a file using bash? (with a plus)

Tags: bash, file, text

This would be the **input**:

```
a b 125
a b 358
d t 485
d f 859
d t 789
a t 154
```

This would be the **output**:

```
2 a b 125
2 d t 485
1 d f 859
1 a t 154
```

**Important**: Note that what i need to do is the following:

1 - Count ocurrences of the first 2 columns concatenated. For example:

```
a b 125
a b 358
```

This would be 2 ocurrences of the sequence *ab*.

2 - Keep the first ocurrence of the id (3rd column) for each sequence. For example:

```
a b 125
a b 358
```

In this case, I would like to output *2 a b 125*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must preserve your desired output order, you can use `awk` and 3-arrays to hold the count of the number of times the first two fields are seen (array `a`), an array that preserves the order the first two fields are encountered (array `b`), and finally an array that maps the first two fields with the first seen of the third field (array `c`):

```
awk -v n=1 '{ a[$1" "$2]++ }
    $1" "$2 in c {next}
    {   b[n++]=$1" "$2; 
        c[$1" "$2]=$3
    }
    END { for (i in b) print a[b[i]], b[i], c[b[i]] }
' file
```

Above `$1" "$2` is a concatenation of the first two fields used as a common index for arrays `a` and `c` and used as the value in array `b` that preserves the order.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file in `file`, you can simply copy and middle-mouse paste the script above into an xterm in the directory containing `file` and your result is in the order you indicate:

```
$ awk -v n=1 '{ a[$1" "$2]++ }
>     $1" "$2 in c {next}
>     {   b[n++]=$1" "$2;
>         c[$1" "$2]=$3
>     }
>     END { for (i in b) print a[b[i]], b[i], c[b[i]] }
> ' file
2 a b 125
2 d t 485
1 d f 859
1 a t 154
```

**Using SUBSEP**

As pointed out by @JonathanLeffler in the comments below, you can also provide the indexing as `a[$1,$2]` used to represent multidimensional arrays where the `','` character is replaced by the builtin `SUBSEP` variable which is `"\034"`. To do so also requires adjustments in the second rule test and the value for the `b` array. With the adjustments, you would have:

```
awk -v n=1 '{ a[$1,$2]++ } 
    $1 SUBSEP $2 in c { next }
    {
        b[n++]=$1 SUBSEP $2
        c[$1,$2]=$3
    }
    END {for (i in b) print a[b[i]], b[i], c[b[i]]}
' file
```

Either concatenation or separation with `SUBSEP` will work here, but for formal multidimensional array simulation `SUBSEP` should be used.

Comment: You could use `[$1, $2]` for the subscripts — that separates the values with `SUBSEP` (default `"\034"`).  You'd have to revise the second line to `c[$1, $2] != "" { next }`, and I suppose `b[n++] = $1 SUBSEP $2`.  I think it is pure coincidence that the sample data has the counts in descending order — the key columns are in the order of appearance, as you said.  (I went off on a wrong track because I assumed that the counts were in descending order — and then realized just in time that they weren't.)

Comment: Happens... Yes, the `[$1, $2]` is a good approach and probably a more formal way of chaining the indexes together. (the short version is I would have had to look up `SUBSEP` for `b` `:)`

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for the test case described:

```
sort -t' ' -k1,2 file | uniq -cw4 | sort -r
```

Comment: This runs into problems if the keys are not single letters but variable length words.  Then the GNU `uniq` command option `-w4` is no longer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys in columns 1 and 2 are variable length, then I think `awk` is the tool of choice.  This is similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60665320/15168) by [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin), but it was developed independently.

```
awk '{ if (count[$1, $2]++ == 0) { line[$1, $2] = $0; order[n++] = $1 SUBSEP $2 } }
     END { for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf "%d %s\n", count[order[i]], line[order[i]] }'
```

The first line increments the count for the entry with columns 1 and 2; if that was 0 (before the increment), then capture the line (indexed by columns 1 and 2), and capture the key (columns 1 and 2, separated by `SUBSEP`) in `order[n++]`.

At the end, process the keys in `order`, indexing the relevant data in `count` and `line`.

For your input data, this produces:

```
2 a b 125
2 d t 485
1 d f 859
1 a t 154
```

But it also works correctly if the keys are variable lengths.  There are numerous possible refinements, such as working out how long the biggest count is so that the counts are right-aligned, and if you're dealing with variable-length keys, you could track which is the longest key in column 1 and column 2, so you could align the keys, too.